# Quandle Definition

Tags: abstract-algebra, definition

A [Quandle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racks_and_quandles) is a set $Q$ with two binary operations $(x,y)\mapsto x\triangleright y$ and $(x,y)\mapsto x\triangleright^{-1} y$ which satisfies three axioms for all $x,y,z\in Q$:

- $x\triangleright x=x$;
- $(x\triangleright y)\triangleright^{-1}y=x=(x\triangleright^{-1}y)\triangleright y$;
- $(x\triangleright y)\triangleright z=(x \triangleright z)\triangleright(y\triangleright z)$.

My question is:

> For each $y\in Q$, does there exist an element $y^{-1}\in Q$ such that 
>   $$x\triangleright^{-1}y=x\triangleright (y^{-1})$$
>   holds true for all $x\in Q$? If yes, is $y^{-1}$ unique for all $y$?

Comment: $y^{-1}$ is not unique at least; consider the abelian quandle $\triangleright:A\times A\to A$ defined on an abelian group $A$ of characteristic 2 as $x\triangleright y = 2y-x$. And I'm skeptical onthe existence of $y^{-1}$ though cannot give a proof.

Answer (score 0):

And no, such an element $y^{-1}$ need not exist. In the special case that $\rhd$ is the same operation as $\rhd^{-1}$ (in which case the quandle is called *involutory*), then of course you can take $y^{-1} = y$. So let's look at the smallest non-involutory quandle. It's the quandle generated by the rotations of the tetrahedron acting on its vertices, and also the only connected quandle of order 4, but you can simply look at its operation table if we take its elements to be ${1,2,3,4}$, namely:
$$\begin{matrix}1 & 4 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 2 & 4 & 1 \\ 4 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\ 2 & 3 & 1 & 4\end{matrix}$$
Now notice that $2 \rhd^{-1} 1 = 4$ and 3 is the only element such that $2 \rhd 3 = 4$, whereas $ 3 \rhd^{-1} 1 = 2$ but 4 is the only element such that $3 \rhd 4 = 2$. Hence, there is no element that can serve as $1^{-1}$ in the sense you describe above.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!